# Which class needs to implement INotifyDataErrorInfo?

Tags: c#, data-binding, silverlight-5.0, inotifydataerrorinfo

In the case of a binding such as

```
<TextBox Text={Binding Path=SomeItem.AnotherItem.Property} />
```

Which class(es) need to implement INotifyDataErrorInfo:

1. The DataContext
2. SomeItem
3. AnotherItem
4. Some combination of these

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
AnotherItem
```

`INotifyDataErrorInfo` must be implemented by object who own's the property to which is bound.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an MVVM pattern , the INotifyDataErrorInfo is usually implemented by the view-model.  This view-model, usually, is then your view's datacontext.